# problems installing civ 5, steam errors... no solution yet

Tags: civilization-5, steam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I play Civ 5 without having Steam installed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10449/can-i-play-civ-5-without-having-steam-installed)

Ok, so let me start of by saying I am deployed. 
I was pretty excited when I found out that there's civ 5 for PC, and I ordered one. I waited for the game for over 3 weeks (mail takes that long to get here), and for past week I was running to post office everyday to see if it came in early. Today it did (great, I have a day off tomorrow), but I have been trying to install it for past 6 hours!!!! all because of that stupid Steam!!! It keeps giving me errors, first it wouldn't start updating, i searched all over to find solutions... as soon as I fixed one thing, another thing came up, when I fixed that, another came up... deleted blob, installed separate steam.exe to replace the other one, renamed to -clearbeta, ran the safe mode, firewall/antivirus off, etc etc... it keeps telling me to either connect to internet, or the system being temporarily unavailable, etc... I am tired! I finally have a day off, and I spent $50 on this game, for me to get another one is 3 weeks! I couldn't care less for online gaming (plus we are not allowed to do that). I wrote an email to steam, nothing from them. Please help! 
p.s. i read something about working with router settings, but no can do. We get free wifi here, and are not allowed to touch it.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10449/can-i-play-civ-5-without-having-steam-installed. You might also want to check out http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4293/how-can-you-install-steam-games-offline.

Comment: thank you, but that does not answer my question. In the thread you mentioned above, only one gentleman mentioned that there is a way around it, but didn't go into detail. Most q/a's have to do with not wanting to install it, i just simply can't, and don't want to throw $50 away.

Comment: If what you want is to somehow skip Steam, then it's the exact same question. If you want us to try and help you troubleshoot the Steam install process, then please edit the question accordingly! Specifically, provide more details about the exact nature of the problem, possibly with error codes.

Comment: hmm, well, I guess it is sort of similar, but there was no answer to that question. I don't feel like bringing up the old thread.

Comment: I sure could use some help thou. I receve messages: steam is temporarily unavailable, and second one is "in order to update, please connect to the internet". I do not know if i have the beta version or not, but i am unable to change the target name on my desktop short cut

Comment: p.s. it stays on steam updating 0% complete, and then gives me the error

Comment: Is it possible that there is a firewall or something which is blocking Steam?  If online gaming isn't allowed, Steam might be blocked as well.  If that is the case, you are unfortunately out of luck.

Comment: it there a way to bypass it? just to activate it? Gentleman that answered the question in the other thread, mentioned about somehow disabling it

Comment: You can edit the question, ilya (the small "edit" link just underneath it). Use it to provide more details about the precise Steam error, instead of via comments. In any case, it is indeed possible that the ports Steam used are blocked in your network... you can ask your network administrator about it. Steam is a pretty respectable service, maybe they won't mind enabling it.